# Libvlc Chromecast .m3u8 in Android

Tags: android, casting, libvlc

can someone help me with LibVLC. I need create a simple app to cast .m3u8 in Chromecast.

I already try Cast SDK, but won't work for my .m3u8
I think need Transcoding on-the-fly and I think LibVLC v3 can handle with that.

you can help me with that ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone who struggled with LibVLC on Android for too long, I advise you move to ExoPlayer. It supports HLS media source (m3u8) and it is specifically made for Android ease of use.

[HLS - ExoPlayer - Implementation Official Docs](https://exoplayer.dev/hls.html)

Comment: Thank you so much!